# How to access a function that's nested inside an override method

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private fun openTrailer() {
    val trailerDialog = Dialog(this)
    val trailerDialogBinding = DialogTrailerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    trailerDialog.setContentView(trailerDialogBinding.root)

    youtubePLayerInit = object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
        override fun onInitializationSuccess(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            youtubePlayer: YouTubePlayer?,
            p2: Boolean
        ) {
            fun loadTrailer2(videoId: String) {
                youtubePlayer?.loadVideo(videoId)
            }
        }

        override fun onInitializationFailure(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?,
        ) {
            toast("la")
        }
    }
    if (!isInitialized) {
        trailerDialogBinding.vvMovieTrailer.initialize(youtubeApiKey, youtubePLayerInit)
        isInitialized = true
    } else {
        Log.e("initializerStatus", "Already Initialized")
    }
    trailerDialog.show()
}
```

How do I access access the `loadTrailer2` function in the main code? `Load Trailer` is the function inside the object of the `YoutubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`. I'm trying to accesss it outside the `open trailer` function, aka in the `onCreate` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it is right now, `loadTrailer2` is a local function declared inside `onInitializationSuccess` - it only exists while that function is running, so you can't access it from outside that scope.

You could move it into the object itself, but since it relies on the `YoutubePlayer` object being passed in, how would you call it? Do you have access to that player in `onCreate`?

If you did have access to it (e.g. when the initialisation first succeeds, you store it in a `ViewModel` or something, and use that next time you create a fragment) you still have an issue: the type of `youtubePlayerInit` is `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener`, and you're adding another method to your object, one that isn't part of that `YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener` interface.

What that means, is nothing actually knows that method exists. If you create that anonymous object inside a function, the compiler sees it as a special type that contains that method, so you can access it directly:

```
interface Thing {
    fun onSomeEvent(code: Int)
}

fun main() {
    doSetup()
}

fun doSetup() {
    val myThing = object : Thing {
        override fun onSomeEvent(code: Int) {
            println("Event code: $code")
        }
        
        fun coolFunction() {
            println("Secret function accessed")
        }
    }
    
    // calling it inside the scope the object was declared in, so the function
    // is visible here
    myThing.coolFunction()
}

>> Secret function accessed
```

but outside of that scope, it just looks like the type declared when creating the `object` (`Thing` in this example):

```
interface Thing {
    fun onSomeEvent(code: Int)
}


fun main() {
    val myThing = doSetup()
    // this only knows it's a Thing, which doesn't have this method
    myThing.coolFunction()
}

fun doSetup(): Thing {
    val myThing = object : Thing {
        override fun onSomeEvent(code: Int) {
            println("Event code: $code")
        }
        
        fun coolFunction() {
            println("Secret function accessed")
        }
    }
    
    return myThing
}

>> Unresolved reference: coolFunction
```

If you wanted to access that function, you'd have to e.g. declare a `CoolFunctionHaver` interface with that function, and either declare `myThing` as that type, or cast it if you really have to

Comment: How About, if I move the function to be nested directly behind the `open trailer`. How would that work? (I mean how would I have to access it it `onCreate`

Comment: Well like I said, ``loadTrailer2`` requires access to a ``YoutubePlayer``, which I'm assuming you don't have when ``onCreate`` runs. The whole point of the callback is you call that ``vvMovieTrailer.initialize`` function, and then *sometime later* it completes and calls ``onInitializationSuccess`` and provides the ``YoutubePlayer`` - this probably happens after ``onCreate`` has finished. You could always store the ``YoutubePlayer`` in a top-level variable, and have a top-level ``loadTrailer`` function check if that's null when you call it, if that works for what you're doing

Comment: can you provide code for that? I don't get it completely

Comment: Look that's the original code of my function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096815/youtubeandroidplayerapi-only-loads-once
can you tell me how to change it?